# Rails4 app - How to run CRON jobs on other server than the one where runs the main app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, cron, digital-ocean

I use [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) (Ubuntu, nginx, unicorn) for my Rails 4 application (the $10/mo plan). There occurred a need to run CRON jobs which will be occurred every 10 minutes.

If I would run these CRON jobs in the 10-minutes intervals on the server where is running the main application, the app would almost surely crush down.

So I am considering running these CRON jobs on another server - the server for $5/mo.
But how to connect these applications and set it up?

Do I have to copy the Rails app also on the second ($5/mo) server? What's the "blueprint" for this procedure?
(I have no experience with it)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy yet one copy of your application to $5 VPS with Capistrano. In deploy script you can configure role and CRON use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to specify where and when you want to run your cron. After that you will have $5 VPS with CRON only.

Comment: But how the data will be copied between servers? Let's say I'll run these CRON jobs on the $5/mo server, I guess the data will be saved on the $5/mo server, or not? How to synchronise the databases then?

Comment: 1) What kind of data? 2) Use one DB.

Comment: Data = data saved in database. So I'll use only one database? The $5/mo server will use the database from the production server? There will be no database server on the $5/mo server?

Comment: Yes, one DB on production server (casual configuration for many small and medium projects).